# Error 500 when check "full source" in violations tab on a JSP

Tags: sonarqube

We use Sonar 3.5.1 and multi languages configuration (with sonar-project.properties).
When we "drill down" to source for a violation an error pop up appear : "Server error. Please contact your administrator. The status of the error is : 500". No more logs in the sonar.log.
This error appear uniquely for a JSP file no for a Java class.

Anyone can help me ?

Regards,

Stéphane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : i upgrade to 3.6.1 and the problem diseppear ;)